# Font size in Chrome/Firefox getting bigger after loading

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

This is happening in both Chrome and Firefox Browsers
Been Having this issue for quite a while now and i tried looking for fixes for this but no luck.
this is happening in every site i browse. i installed ccleaner and malwarebytes because i thought this was a malware/adware problem.

Image below is the site Still loading
[image: Before the site loads]

This one after the site fully loads on chrome

[image: After the site load]

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? Could be some rogue CSS or Javascript messing up your code. Hit F12 and inspect that title element to see what styles are being applied to it and if any scripts are occurring or errorring out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSS reset, it will allow for more consistent styling across the browsers. You could use the [CSS reset from YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/).

---

Alternatively, you could define absolute `font-size` for the `html` or `body`, and then use relative sizes like `em` and `%` for all other elements.

For absolute styling of body/html tags, you could do this:

```
body {
  font-size: //a number in pixels;
}
```

And then at the bottom of your CSS file add this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  body {
    font-size: //a number in pixels;      
    }
}
```